# meteor-roles not working as expected it returning false

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

we are using meteor `METEOR@1.4.0.1` and added `alanning:roles` for managing role.
below code that we using for apply role.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    console.log("on account create");
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(user._id,'admin')
    console.log(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(),'admin'));
    return user;
});

Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(),'admin') return false
```

help us what wrong.

Comment: It might just be a timing issue - remember that the call to addUsersToRoles does an update to the database, which isn't instant. If you check the db manually, has it done the work of adding the role?

Comment: @Mike King - i was keep trying from console to check status of Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(),'admin') but it alwase return false and also i have check that roles is subscribe and it returning all available roles

Answer (score 1):

with [alanning-roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles), you don't need to include that to Accounts.onCreateUser.

You just need to use `Roles.addUserToRoles()` after you've inserted the new document. Like so:

`const id = Accounts.createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: "apple1",
    profile: { name: user.name }
  });
Roles.addUsersToRoles(id,'whateverRole')`

Based on their [README.md](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles):

> Note that the Roles.addUsersToRoles call needs to come after Accounts.createUser or Accounts.onCreate or else the roles package won't be able to find the user record (since it hasn't been created yet).

Comment: have you tested with METEOR@1.4.0.1

Comment: Thanks for your finding i found issue meteor account start working with login and signup with package accounts-password but for roles it must required accounts-base package.